# Prevent Windows Live Mail to download all messages from IMAP

Tags: windows-live-mail

I'm trying the *Window Live Mail* client. Simple and beautiful. However I'm used to an IMAP client that only downloads headers. *Windows Live Mail* automatically creates a list of tasks to download all messages from all directories when closing the client. Is it possible to avoid this?

It's good because I can work offline and have a backup, but it takes extremely long to perform. With a hundred thousand emails, this task can take a whole day to perform. What should I look for in the settings?

Answer (score 5):

I finally found something.

Right-click an IMAP folder than you can select the synchronization option, unfortunately this has to be done for each folder. By default the sync is set to download the messages, you can choose between *new messages only*, *headers only*, or *no synchronization* at all. It's not great but there is the option.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to your account's properties and uncheck the checkbox that says "include this account when synchronizing".
Just like you said, WLM allows us to select whether to download all messages, headers only or nothing at all. There is a very important option missing: "Download message text only". We should be able to download all message texts without downloading all attachments. I wonder why Microsoft forgot to contrive that option in all its mail client software such as OE, WM, WLM and Outlook.